# To String Conversion while doing Join in LINQ

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5, sql-function

I am using LINQ query to fetch the data from database and also doing joins in the LINQ query as,

```
(
from accountTransaction in AccountTransactions
join xlkpQualifier in Enumerations on 
    accountTransaction.LkpQualifier.ToString() equals xlkpQualifier.Value 
select top accountTransaction)
.Take(10);
```

I am getting Exception on `accountTransaction.LkpQualifier.ToString()` that System.ToString() can't be used in LINQ Entities.

But I am getting problem here in conversion to string  on Join.
How can I do it?

Comment: ToString is not a recognized SQL operation, so I would assume its choking on that.

Comment: I believe that `ToString()` cannot be converted to SQL. Which SQL types are the fields `LkpQualifier` and `xlkpQualifier`?

Comment: I am getting Problem with ToString(), And I have to do conversion for the Join, Because LINQ doesn't Emplicitly converts data.

Answer (score -1):

Until you provide us with some more information on the SQL types of the fields `LkpQualifier` and `xlkpQualifier`, I will answer as follows:

You should either **(1)** change your table data schema and set the same data types or **(2)** write the raw SQL version of your LINQ query and execute the query

### Raw SQL query using EF:

```
using (var db = new Entities())
{
    string myQuery = "SELECT * FROM Table";

    var result = new ObjectQuery<DbDataRecord>(myQuery, db);
    var resultList = result.ToList();
}
```

In the raw SQL query itself, you will probably have to use the `CAST` function with the right type:

```
CAST(Enumerations.xlkpQualifier AS System.Int32)
```

### Raw SQL query without using EF:

There is also a way to write raw SQL without using EF (useful when your table doesn't have the primary key set and you don't have access to change that):

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table";

        var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); // or other variations
    }
}
```